# asp.net program affects result in search engine

Tags: c#, asp.net, search-engine

Is there anything I can do while coding in Asp.net to make my website come on top in search engines for general keywords? (For example : cars...assuming that my site is wwww.joshautos123.com)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with ASP.NET Josh,

You need to start investigating SEO in general (Search Engine Optimization)

This is a pretty broad topic ([more info here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization)) covering everything from keywords, content, url formatting, and cross linking to lots of different sites/resources.

The best thing you can do if your only developing it (and not responsible for marketting)
is that you put together a well designed, clean, standards compliant site.

Answer (score 1):

you can follow the search engine optimization guidlines for your header, images etc.
that the way you can acheive it.
Anyways, you can read [**this tutorial**](http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2008/08/16/Search-Engine-Optimization-for-ASP.NET-Web-Sites.aspx), it will help you.

for more, you can create a good master page with good meta tages. it will help you...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit "black hat" to me.

The most important aspect of SEO is content, So as long as you have lots of good, meaningful content relating to "cars" you stand a good chance.

Next up, you want lots of reliable sources to link to you with meaningful keywords in the links. And a whole bunch more SEO tricks

When making the ASP.NET application, you can make sure you facilitate SEO best practices, but at the end of the day, if your site is full of nonsens and people don't think it's worth linking to. Your'e not going to get very good rankings.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the SEO enhancements can be done beside of asp.net.
so just add the right tags and words to the aspx file.
or for dynamic pages, generate them from the content.

but what you should have also in mind are 2 things:
first of all, run all of your system under one url. and all other ones should be redirected with 301 to it (e.g. redirect http://joshautos123.com to www.joshautos123.com with 301 redirect)
and do not use subdomains for different parts (that will split your search rank)

and second, you should use the asp.net mvc.
because one important part of seo is, that the right content (e.g. titles, real car names, etc) are in the URL.

rest was already said by the other answers....

Answer (score 0):

Try visiting this website for a start [Using Meta Tags with Master Pages in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/PageTags.aspx)